# Magento get payment date in a custom report grid

Tags: magento-1.8, collection, payment, sales

I want to add "the date that customer paid the bill" to a report grid for "sales_flat_order_item" table.

For getting result,I have to join two tables "sales_flat_order_status_history" and "sales_flat_order" , before joining them to "sales_flat_order_item".

Now I have two questions :

1- Is there anyway to join two tables before joining them to the collection in magento?

If the answer is NO :

2- How can I add the payment date to my grid?

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the collection you're using and overwrite the _initSelect() function with the joins you want.